# Prove A contains at least one subset of 4# (bi , distinct integers) / b1*b2*b3*b4=m^4

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Let A be a set of 2015 distinct positive integers such that no element
>   of A is divisible by any prime larger than 25.    Prove that A
>   contains **at least** one subset of four distinct integers whose product
>   is the fourth power of an integer.

I try to solve this exercise, but I have no luck. I divided the logical steps to understand more what I need to prove.

> (1) A=2015 positive integers. No element of A is divisible by any
>   prime larger than 25.

Therefore, I said:

B={Set of  2015  distinct integers}

P=primes greater that 25={29,31,37,41,47,53,59,61,67,71,…,2011,2015}

M=multiples of P

Then A=B-P-M

> (2) There is at least one subset B included in A, B[b1,b2,b3,b4] such
>   that b1*b2*b3*b4=m^4 where b1, b2, b3, and b4 are distinct, and m
>   integer.

I believe, I need to find A, with the restriction given, and after doing it I can took at least 1 set {b1,b2,b3,b4} such as (2) is true and then I will be done?? Is it right? Please I need help to understand such exercise. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be looking at the primes greater than 25 at all. Instead, count the primes less than 25. Suppose you were to write each element of $A$ as the product of powers of these primes. Then look at the vector of exponents. The claim is that there will exist 4 vectors whose sum is divisible by 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number $2015$ is very weak.We will prove the stronger problem:

**Problem:** *Let $A$ be a set of $1537$ distinct positive integers such that no element of $A$ is divisible by any prime larger than $25$. Prove that $A$ contains at least one subset of four distinct integers whose product is the fourth power of an integer.*

***Solution:*** Every element of $A$ is of the form $2^{\alpha_1}\cdot 3^{\alpha_2}\cdot...\cdot 19^{\alpha_8}\cdot 23^{\alpha_9}$.Now every $\alpha_i$ leaves residue $0$ or $1$ when divided by $2$,so by Pigeon Hole Principle from any $2^9+1=513$ elements of $A$ there will be two of the form $2^{\alpha_1}\cdot 3^{\alpha_2}\cdot...\cdot 19^{\alpha_8}\cdot 23^{\alpha_9}$(we will call this number $a_1$) and $2^{\beta_1}\cdot 3^{\beta_2}\cdot...\cdot 19^{\beta_8}\cdot 23^{\beta_9}$(we will call this number $b_1$) such that $\alpha_i\equiv\beta_i,i=\overline{1,9}$.From here it follows that $a_1b_1$ is the square of an integer.

Now take those two numbers away from $A$.We choose other $513$ elements of $A$.Again,by Pigeon Hole Principle there will be two numbers $a_2,b_2$ such that $a_2b_2$ is the square of an integer.Take those two numbers away from $A$.

We will procced this way until $A$ is left with only $513$ elements.From those final $513$ elements,By Pigeon Hole Principle,there will be two such that their product is the square of an integer.

Therefore we will have $\frac{1537-513}{2}+1=513$ pairs $(a_i,b_i)$ of elements of $A$ such that $c_i=a_ib_i,i=\overline{1,513}$ is the square of an integer.

Observe that $\sqrt{c_i}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\sqrt{c_i}$ is of the form $2^{\alpha_1}\cdot 3^{\alpha_2}\cdot...\cdot 19^{\alpha_8}\cdot 23^{\alpha_9}$,so again by Pigeon Hole Principle there will be two numbers $1\le i\le j\le 513$ such that $\sqrt{c_i}\cdot\sqrt{c_j}=a^2$ for some integer $a$.From here it follows that $a^4=c_ic_j=a_ib_ia_jb_j$.Now just note that $a_i,b_i,a_j,b_j\in A$.This ends our proof.

Comment: First of all thanks. I have some question regarding why you said that 2015 is very weak number and later you chose 1537? In my case I will use ((2015-513)/2)+1= 752 pairs (ai,bi)? That is correct, no?

Comment: @Electro82 Suppose that $|A|=n$.As you pointed out,it's all about the number of pairs $(a_i,b_i)$,which are in number of $\frac{n-513}{2}+1$.All we want is $\frac{n-513}{2}+1\ge 2^9+1=513$(in order to use Pigeon Hole Principle),which implies $n\ge 1537$.

Comment: If I don't misunderstand then, for any number that (n−513)/2+1≥2^9+1=513  I can use the Pigeon Hole Principle, and  I will always have ci=aibi  with i=1 to 513?

Comment: @Electro82 You've got the idea.